# Oracle Forms 12c - BI Publisher integration error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

I´m doing some test with Oracle Forms 12c and Oracle BI Publisher Trial, all in the forms compiling well but when I run the forms, it gives an error: 
"FRM-41223: BI Publisher integration error"

This is my code, it is a unit program that´s activated when I press a button

```
PROCEDURE EJECUTA_BIP IS
    bi_username varchar2(20);
    bi_password varchar2(20);
    repid REPORT_OBJECT;
    v_rep varchar2(256);
    rep_status varchar2(256);
    v_xmlpserver varchar2(256);
BEGIN
    -- Servidor de BI Publisher
    v_xmlpserver := 'http://HOST:PORT/xmlpserver/';
    bi_username := 'username';
    bi_password := 'password';

    -- Identify the Report Object.
    repid := find_report_object ('BIP_P');

    -- Before reaching this point be sure to obtain the username and password for BI-Pub.
    -- Pass in the username and password. This is required.
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_USER, bi_username);
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_PASSWORD, bi_password);

    --
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_SSL_CONNECTION, OPTIONAL);
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_SERVICE_LOCATION, v_xmlpserver||'/services/v2/ScheduleService?wsdl');
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_REPORT_PATH, '/Samples/1. Overview/Salary Report.xdo');
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_REPORT_LOCALE, 'ES-es');
    --Tipo de formato de salida, p.e.: html,pdf,rtf,xslx,csv
    SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_REPORT_FORMAT, 'pdf');

    -- Ask BIP to run the report.
    v_rep := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(repid);
END;
```

Please help!
Regards!

Comment: I´m doing some test, and the form fail when it was on the last line

"-- Ask BIP to run the report. v_rep := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(repid);"

When it try to run that line, it fail

Please help, someone who know what happen

Comment: Someone? I'm facing the same problem